# Live DVD hangs at GRUB2 on boot

Tags: boot, grub2, livecd

I have a [live Slackware 14.1 64-bit iso](http://www.slackware.com/getslack/torrents.php) that hangs at "Welcome to Grub!". MD5 sums check out for the downloaded image. The computer in question has successfully booted live images of other operating systems.

Where should I begin to investigate this matter further, or, are there alternative boot methods for getting into a live image on DVD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full disclosure:  I did a very dumb thing in trying to solve this problem, and I did it on purpose.

**Don't** do the dumb thing I did.  Which was **boot into a working live environment, unmount `/`, and then `#dd if=/path/to/iso.img of=/path/to/former/root`**.

What does this do?  Kills your MBR (makes your computer unbootable).

Fortunately, I have a separate partition for `/home`, and I did the dumb thing on a personal computer, so I didn't loose any files that I'm particularly attached to (farewell, `/var/log` & friends!) but now I get to enjoy the dubious pleasure of trying to reconfigure my entire OS.

**How I managed to actually solve the problem** originally posed in this post was by taking the [desired ISO](http://www.slackware.com/getslack/torrents.php) and running the `isohybrid` [command](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Isohybrid) on the image, *then* `dd`ing it to a USB drive... et voila! Bootable, Slacky goodness.